# Exercise of real analysis

Tags: real-analysis

How to prove that $$\mathbb{Q}\subseteq \bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}T_n$$ with $T_n=\left\{\frac{k}{n}:k\in \mathbb{Z}, |k|<2^n\right\}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would take some element $\frac{p}{q} \in \mathbb{Q}$ and try to guarantee a particular $n$ so that we know that $\frac{p}{q} \in T_n$. I know that as long as $p < 2^n$, my $n$ will suffice for the numerator. What about the denominator? We might hope that we could just choose $n = q$, but this may not work, as this requires that $p < 2^q$.

So let's choose an equivalent fraction, like $\frac{lp}{lq}$ for some integer $l$. We'll let $n = lq$, and we know we're okay so long as $lp < 2^{lq}$. Fortunately, as $l$ increases, $2^{lq}$ increases much faster (exponential growth) than $lp$ (linear growth) regardless of $p,q$, so I know there will be some sufficiently large $l$ that will work.